# How to move files larger then 300KB to a different location with Perl

Tags: perl

I have a Perl script (`move_file.pl`) and need to add an extra functionality.
Files larger then 300KB must be moved to another location and the script should then send an email warning.

How can I read the size of a file and move the "larger files" to a different location?

Current move script:

```
  opendir(D, "$source_dir") or mail_die ("Fout bij lezen van directory $source_dir : $!" ); 
my @allfiles = sort( grep { -f "$source_dir/$_" } readdir D); #Lees alle bestanden uit de huidige werk directory 
closedir(D);

my @filelist = grep { !/^.+(\._cpcnv_)$/i } @allfiles;  #Alle bestanden die NIET passen in het patroon *._cpcnv_  (Case insensitive) 
foreach my $filename (@filelist) 
{
  my $source_file = "$source_dir/$filename";
  my $target_file = "$target_dir/$filename";  
  rename $source_file , $target_file or mail_die ("Fout bij hernoemen van bestand $source_file naar $target_file : $! \n" );
  print "Bestand $source_file verplaatst naar $target_file.\n";
}
debug "Succesvol beeindigd!\n";
exit;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will sort out the larger files for some special processing, and change the target directory in the process:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my($THRESHOLD) = 300 * 1024;

my($SOURCE_DIR) = "/tmp/src";
my($TARGET_DIR) = "/tmp/dst";
my($LARGE_DIR)  = "/tmp/bigfiles";

foreach my $filename (@ARGV) {
    next if -d $filename;

    my($source_file) = "$SOURCE_DIR/$filename";
    my($target_file) = "$TARGET_DIR/$filename";

    my($size) = (stat($source_file))[7];
    $target_file = mail_warn($source_file, $filename, $size) if ($size > $THRESHOLD);

    print qq{"TARGET_DIR: "$target_file"\n};
}

sub mail_warn
{
    my($source_file, $filename, $size) = @_;
    print qq{File "$source_file" too big! [$size]\n};

    my($new_target) = "$LARGE_DIR/$filename";
    $new_target;
}
```

A small sample with some made-up data:

```
$ /tmp/foo *
"TARGET_DIR: "/tmp/dst/aaa"
"TARGET_DIR: "/tmp/dst/bbb"
File "/tmp/src/bbb" too big! [3014026]
"TARGET_DIR: "/tmp/bigfiles/bbb"
"TARGET_DIR: "/tmp/dst/ccc"
File "/tmp/src/ddd" too big! [501130]
"TARGET_DIR: "/tmp/bigfiles/ddd"
"TARGET_DIR: "/tmp/dst/eee"
```